# JMeter unescapeHtml on a variable value

Tags: jmeter

If I have a BeanShell PostProcessor with the following script:

```
vars.put("avar", ${__unescapeHtml("&lt;escele&gt;esceleValue&lt;/escele&gt;")});
vars.put("bvar", "&lt;escele&gt;esceleValue&lt;/escele&gt;");
vars.put("cvar", ${__unescapeHtml(vars.get("bvar"))});
```

I get the following in the Debug PostProcessor:

```
avar=<escele>esceleValue</escele>
bvar=&lt;escele&gt;esceleValue&lt;/escele&gt;
cvar=&lt;escele&gt;esceleValue&lt;/escele&gt;
```

I would expect cvar's value to match avar's value.  Is there a way to do this?

Ultimately I am trying to get a statement like the following to work with escaped XML in the response data.  In the process I tried PostProcessor extractors that successfully put all the response data in a variable and then tried to unescape the variable as in the above test case.  I assume the issue is the same using a variable or using "prev.getResponseDataAsString()".

```
vars.put("avar", ${__unescapeHtml(prev.getResponseDataAsString())});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend stop inlining [JMeter Functions and/or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions) into scripting-enabled test elements as it may cause unexpected behaviour w.r.t ValueReplacer and in case of [JSR223 Sampler and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) will definitely lead to performance degradation as scripts containing variables and functions references cannot be compiled into bytecode.

Given you:

1. Already using Beanshell
2. Know that [__unescapeHtml()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__unescapeHtml) function is using [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) under the hood according to the function documentation

Why just not to call code directly like:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;


vars.put("avar", ${__unescapeHtml("&lt;escele&gt;esceleValue&lt;/escele&gt;")});
vars.put("bvar", "&lt;escele&gt;esceleValue&lt;/escele&gt;");
vars.put("cvar", ${__unescapeHtml(vars.get("bvar"))});
vars.put("dvar", StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(vars.get("bvar")));

log.info(vars.get("dvar"));
```

[image: Beanshell String Escape]